# how to use last 2 frames' informations when I use clip.fl_image(process_image)

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, moviepy

I need to post process one video clips, I have one method called process_image, which give me some heat_map, which are 720x1280 binary numpy array.

Here is how I initialize it to all 0. img size is 720x1280.

```
heatmap = np.zeros_like(img[:,:,0])
```

Let's say I want to average heatmap over last 2 frames: heatmap(current) + 2/3 heatma(last frame) + 1/3 heatmap(2 frames ago). How should I store it and load it?

```
def process_image(img):
    heat_map = another_method(img)
    return heat_map
clip = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip.fl_image(process_image)
```